# CSS external font: what's the right syntax?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

All the documentation I've searched says that the right syntax to load external font files in CSS is the following:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'JosefinSansLight';
src: url('josefinsans-light-webfont.eot');
src: url('josefinsans-light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('josefinsans-light-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('josefinsans-light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('josefinsans-light-webfont.svg#JosefinSansLight') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

(Provided one has the font in all the above formats, of course, which I do).

However, the above syntax doesn't work for me in Safari 5.0.2 or Firefox 9: the font simply doesn't load. On the other hand, when I try just this:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Josefin Sans';
src: url('JosefinSans-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

The font does get loaded and displayed. (I don't have IE available to test).

What's wrong? I should mention that I originally had only the TTF file (the one I'm loading in the second example), and that I generated the other versions (the ones that don't load) using Fontsquirrel.

**Edit:** checking my Apache logs, I see that the browser is definitely pulling the fonts (therefore, they are in the right location). Firefox just loads the TTF font in the second case (as one would expect), while in the first case it only loads the EOT font (the first one in the code), not the others. OTOH, Safari loads the TTF, but doesn't seem to load anything in the first case. I don't see any 404 errors related to fonts in the logs either.

Comment: Make sure you have all your files in the right location.

Answer (score 0):

OK, it seems that I found the solution. The problem is that my CSS code lacked ONE font format, .OTF (OpenType). I added the following line:

```
     url('fonts/JosefinSans-light.otf') format('opentype'),
```

And both Safari and Firefox recognized the font.

Now: the problem, of course, is that I didn't add the OpenType font before because Fontsquirrel didn't generate it for me in the first place; it was the only format missing. I had to take another OTF file that I had, rename it to "JosefinSans-light.otf" and put it in place, in order to test it. So the question now becomes: how can I generate an OTF font file from the TTF, EOT... ones that I have? Or is this unnecessary, and I'm just behind the times? (I should mention that I'm still on a Mac OS X 10.5.8, and don't have any other computer to test this thing on right now).

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/ to generate your code for you? I would be surprised if they were doing it wrong :)

Comment: Have you read the question? He said the first snippet is generated by Font Squirrel.

Comment: whoops -- guess I missed that at the end. But -- like it said, I doubt if they are doing it wrong.

Answer (score -1):

In http://www.google.com/webfonts they load it externally like this:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Didact+Gothic&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

and then you just do font-family: 'Didact Gothic', sans-serif; where you need it! I've never used fontsquirrel, but maybe it something like that?

And if loading them by url inside .css file, check that the path is correct